# Use dp or px in canvas for Android Game Programming?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a little problem with my game. Let's assume that there's a game room of 1024x800 (px) and you can slide it to see more content.

When I place two objects (one next to other), based on the original dimensions, it looks OK on a mdpi device, but in hdpi (for example) they are "closer" (it must be because their bitmaps are larger but the "x" and "y" coordinates are the same).

Here's an example:

[image]

So, I think that I must make the game room larger in hdpi with a Rule of Three. First, I thought that I can do it just in the draw method (`Canvas.drawBitmap`) but it affected some collisions (touch events didn't match, for example). I can't make the rule in every single line where I used X&Y coordinates because I did all my levels and game physics considering the original unity (pixels).

Here is my draw method:

```
protected void drawSprite(int x, int y, Canvas canvas){
    int xv = isHUD?0:lw.getXView();
    int yv = isHUD?0:lw.getYView();
    canvas.drawBitmap(sprite_index, x+xv, y+yv, paint);
}
```

`getXView()` and `getYView()` returns the coordinate of the actual slide of the view.

And this is a method that I used to check collisions:

```
public Rect getShape() { 
    int xv = isHUD?0:lw.getXView();
    int yv = isHUD?0:lw.getYView();
    return new Rect(x+xv,y+yv,x+width+xv,y+height+yv);
}
```

What should I do?

Considering that I'm going to put a "Level Editor" in which the players are going to share their creations, storing the "id" and XY coordinates on a database.

Comment: Sorry. LW variable is the reference of the SurfaceView.

Comment: Since you want the game area to be the same virtual world size on all devices you need your own game pixel size which then maps to do.  You don't want dp fir your characters since you don't want your characters the same physical size on a nexus 7  compared to a nexus 4. You do want to use dp for touch controls however.  I'm looking at the exact same issue and will be interested to see further comments and suggestions.